# Why is the plot coming out empty for this Matlab code?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

**Code**

```
clear;clc
T=800;
Pc=48.45;
Tc=375;
w=0.153;
R=82.06;
a=((0.45724)*(R^2)*(Tc^2))/Pc;
b=((0.07780)*R*Tc)/Pc;
B=(0.37464+(1.54226*w)-(0.26992*(w^2)));
Tr=T/Tc;
s=(1+(B*(1-sqrt(Tr))))^2;
for Vm=90:5:1000
    P=((R*T)/(Vm-b))-((a*s)/((Vm)^2+(2*b*Vm)-b^2));
end
plot(Vm, P)
```

**Problem**

Every time I run this code, it comes out with a completely empty plot with just numbers on both axes as the image shown below. I've checked my code a few times, but I still can't find the problem, especially since the code runs with no errors. The result I am supposed to be getting on this plot is the behavior of P as the value of Vm increases.

[The result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyYRv.jpg)

**Additional information about the source of the question**

Here's the original question if you're interested (Exercise 1).

[The original question (Exercise 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sx9s.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying your variables. You'll see `Vm` is not an array, rather it's a single-valued scalar. When you loop over `Vm` it takes one value at a time; it doesn't build an array.

MATLAB can do calculations on multiple values at once, so if you define `Vm` to be an array and drop the loop I'm guessing it'll work...

Try something like this (replace the for-loop with these lines):

```
Vm = 90:5:1000
P=((R*T)./(Vm-b))-((a*s)./((Vm).^2+(2*b.*Vm)-b^2));
```

`P` will then be an array. Notice we use `.*` rather than `*` when multiplying by the array `Vm` since we want to do element-wise multiplication, rather than matrix multiplication. Similarly we use `./` rather than `/` and `.^` rather than `^`.

EDIT: If you *need* to use a for-loop then you could define both `P` and `Vm` as arrays, and then work on each element separately within a loop:

```
Vm = 90:5:1000;
P = NaN(size(Vm));
for i=1:numel(Vm)
    P(i)=((R*T)./(Vm(i)-b))-((a*s)./((Vm(i)).^2+(2*b.*Vm(i))-b^2));
end
```

Since the above is working on scalar values, it doesn't matter if you use `.*` or `*`...

Comment: I tried that, but I am still getting the same exact empty plot.

Comment: Hmmm, okay, Just logged on to my MATLAB machine and tried it out and it works fine for me, I get a nice plot that looks a bit like an exponential decay? Try again? Just to be clear, you replace the for-loop with those two lines. You don't do the for loop.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I reread your answer and noticed you said to eliminate the for loop. It works without the for-loop without a problem, however, on the original question, it's required for me to use a for-loop for this code. Do you think there's any way to go around this problem by using a for-loop?

Comment: Seems a bit stupid to insist on a for-loop (tell your teacher that for extra credit)... But you could do: ``Vm = 90:5:1000;
P = NaN(size(Vm));
for i=1:numel(Vm);
    P(i)=((R*T)./(Vm(i)-b))-((a*s)./((Vm(i)).^2+(2*b.*Vm(i))-b^2));
end;
plot(Vm, P)``

Comment: @Justin You should edit that into your answer.  And yes, it is stupid, but a lot of teachers think forcing students to use a `for`-loop in unnecessary circumstances is good for learning the language, which is wrong.